# Problema em upload de imagem Laravel/Intervention

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel

Estou com um problema quando tento fazer o upload de uma imagem, pois bem, quando dou submit no form ele retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException
Can't write image data to path (public/images/products/2014-06-01-16:24:38-581165_571926502843010_889453779_n.jpg)
```

Pois bem, imaginei que podia ser problema de permissão, fui lá e dei permissão 777 no diretório, mas o danado continua dando o mesmo erro.
Segue o meu código:

```
public function postCreate(){
            $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),Product::$rules);

            if($validator->passes()){
                    $product = new Product();
                    $product->category_id   = Input::get('category_id');
                    $product->title                 = Input::get('title');
                    $product->description   = Input::get('description');
                    $product->price                 = Input::get('price');
                    $product->availability  = Input::get('availability');

                    $image = Input::file('image');
                    $filename = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s').'-'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
                    Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize('468,249')->save('public/images/products/'.$filename);
                    $product->image                 = 'images/products/'.$filename;
                    $product->save();

                    return Redirect::to('admin/products/index')
                            ->with('message','Produto cadastrado');
            }
}
```

Comment: Não tem como disponibilizar uma mensagem de erro mais verbosa? É que só essa mensagem de erro é muito ampla. Pode dar margem a muita coisa.

Answer (score 1):

Agradeço a todas as respostas, porém, resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
$filename = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s').'.'.Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
Image::make(Input::file('image')->getRealPath())->resize('468,249')->save( public_path('img/products/'.$filename));
```

Forneci o caminho absoluto do arquivo e não o relatio, a partir da raiz do projeto. Com isso ele fez o upload, a solução foi dada numa pergunta que fiz no grupo Laravel Brasil.

[Pergunta no grupo Laravel Brasil](https://www.facebook.com/groups/laravelbrasil/742164629138928/?notif_t=group_comment)

Muito obrigado pela ajuda de todos!!!

Answer (score 0):

Não sou conhecedor de Laravel, mas sugiro uma mudança no nome do arquivo.

Não se qual S.O. está usando mas sugiro remover o caractere **":"** do nome do seu arquivo, dado que no Windows e no Linux ele é um caractere inválido. Vide documentação do [Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177506) e uma recomendação neste [site](http://www.mtu.edu/umc/services/web/cms/characters-avoid/). Troque **":"** por **"_"** ou qualquer outro caractere válido e veja o resultado.

Adaptando a seguinte linha:

```
$filename = date('Y-m-d-H_i_s').'-'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
```

Comment: Então, fiz essa alteração mas o erro persiste. Se por acaso eu tbm colocar como um hash md5, dá o mesmo erro tbm:  $filename = md5(date('Y-m-d-H_i_s')).'-'.$image->getClientOriginalName();

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
public function postCreate(){
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),Product::$rules);

    if($validator->passes()){
            $product = new Product();
            $product->category_id   = Input::get('category_id');
            $product->title         = Input::get('title');
            $product->description   = Input::get('description');
            $product->price         = Input::get('price');
            $product->availability  = Input::get('availability');

            $image = Input::file('image');
            $filename = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s').'-'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
            Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize('468,249')->save('images/products/'.$filename);
            $product->image         = 'images/products/'.$filename;
            $product->save();

            return Redirect::to('admin/products/index')
                    ->with('message','Produto cadastrado');
    }
}
```

Porque se colocou `public` no `save` e não precisa, por isso não é caminho válido. Por padrão não precisa colocar o `public` que o `framework` já reconhece tal caminho